# How to get the client certificate in jboss

Tags: ssl, jboss, certificate

I am using jboss as the server and my java program as the client, I have modified the `server.xml` file in jboss to send certificate from server to the client. this happens automatically, when the requesting client has the same domain as the domain in the server keystore. 
But I want the jboss server to validate the client certificate also. How can I send the client certificate to jboss and receive it in jboss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to achieve a two way ssl so lookup "jboss two way ssl".

The steps would be similar to setting up ssl on the server ; the only difference would be that you would need to import the client cert into the server truststore (assuming the client cert is self-signed).

Comment: How to make the client(java program) send the certificate to jboss. In jboss you only have to edit server.xml file and make it point to the keystore containing the certificate.

Comment: If you take a look at the tutorial given below, it states that you need to set clientAuth="true" in server.xml ; no other code change is required.  

http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/08/two-way-ssl-on-tomcat-jboss.html